# GitHuB repository to remote server

Tags: github

Is there anyway I can push changes from my Github Repository to a remote server automatically?

I would like to deploy changes in master branch in my github repository  to a remote deployment server. If possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve what you want with a Git post-commit hook. whether or not this is a wise thing to be doing is another matter entirely.

Hrm. Somehow my link to http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.3.3/hooks.html isn't showing up, but that's what you want to read.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I might have found a solution. 
Capistrano might hold the answer, although my application is non ruby.

Here's a blog post I found, and I will try to implement it. 
[Automated deployment](http://www.simplisticcomplexity.com/2006/08/16/automated-php-deployment-with-capistrano/)